# Taking data from a sql query in php and sending it to another php

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

So, i have a php page that makes a combobox by taking data from a database. After i interrogate the database i want to save the selection  and send it to another php page. But, the problem is it doesn't reach it.

```
<form action ="sending.php" method="POST" >
<?php
     $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '','printers');
     mysql_select_db("printers", $link);

     $query = "SELECT name_printer FROM insurers";
                    // Execute it, or return the error message if there's a problem.
     $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

     $dropdown = "<select name='users' class='dropdown-menu'>";

     while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
           $dropdown .= "\r\n<option value='{$row['name_printer']}'>
          {$row['name_printer']}</option>";
          }
          $dropdown .= "\r\n</select>";
          echo $dropdown;
                    ?>
                    <br><br>

      <input type="hidden" name="selected_text" id="selected_text" value="" />
      <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search"/>
</form>
```

And the sending.php

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['search']))
{

    $makerValue = $_POST['users']; // make value

    $maker = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['selected_text']); // get the selected text
    var_dump( $maker);
}
?>
```

What it prints is string(0) "".

Comment: If you don't set ``selected_text`` via JavaScript the value will always be empty - because it is hidden and the value is ``""`` in HTML.

Comment: selected_text is a empty hidden input with no value, so there is nothing wrong with your code, it returns correctly what it gets. You should vardump your select, give it a name and id. Additionally, you have to add a selected to the <option>. BUT i think you are filling the hidden field with javascript after a option is clicked in the select list, so the issue is probably that there is something wrong with your javascript.

Comment: actually i'm not using javascript at all. should i make a function to set selected_text dynamic ? or is just setting the value to visible a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is with the `$maker` variable, it is set from an escaped `$_POST['selected_text']` which if you look in the html the value is set to `value=""`, so by var_dumping it you would not receive any output.

What you should do instead is use `mysql_real_escape` to escape the `$makerValue` rather than `$_POST['selected_text']`.

That way it will dump the data received from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are already getting selected_text from bellow statement :

```
$makerValue = $_POST['users'];
```

So you can use bellow code directly :

```
$maker = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['users']);
```

One more thing,

```
mysql_real_escape_string()
```

is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0